# How do I get the id of the object who's association I've extended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :things do 
        def [](kind)
            find(:first, :conditions => ["kind = ?", kind.to_s])
        end
    def []=(kind, config)
        thing = self[kind]

        if thing.nil?
            #create  new thing
            ap self # prints all things that person has
        else
            # update 
        end
    end
end
```

With the above code, I can do something like `person.things[:table]` and it will find a thing with person_id of whatever person's id is, and kind of table.  The first method is fine.

It's the second method that I don't know how to implement.
If I want to set the configuration of a table, I want to do it like this `person.things[:table] = {:my => "config"}`

That will be fine if the table already exists.
But what if I want to create a new `thing`?

Normally, creating a Thing would look like this:

```
thing = Thing.new({
  person_id => person[:id],
  kind => "table"
  config => {}
})
```

but, since I'm doing an association extension, and want to create a new object, how do I get the person id?

using
ruby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this recently, but have you tried

```
proxy_association.owner
```

inside the extension? This should return the `Person`, I believe.

Documentation: [RoR Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions).

**Edit**: I just noticed that in your example, a `Person` is not an ActiveRecord model? Was that an omission?

For Rails 2.3.14, you want to use [AssociationProxy's](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy) `proxy_owner` method.
then just do `things.proxy_owner[:id]`

Comment: sorry, person is an active record model. So, .owner returns the instance of person?

Comment: yeah, for the id `proxy_association.owner.id` should get you the id of the Person: 
thing = Thing.new({
  person_id => proxy_association.owner.id,
  kind => "table"
  config => {}
})

Comment: i got `NoMethodError: undefined method `owner'`. I forgot to mention that I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.14. does that matter?

Comment: found it: proxy_owner, i'll update your question with the link to rails 2.3.x and accept